Error: ckeditor-duplicated-modules When Using Multiple Instances
I am experiencing an issue with CKEditor 5 in my React project where I'm using two CKEditor instances: one from Formio and another standalone instance. When both instances are used, I encounter the following error:
Description of the Issue:
In my React application, I have the following setup:

CKEditor from Formio:
This is included as part of a form component
provided by the Formio library.
Standalone CKEditor 5 Instance:
This is implemented directly in my application using the CKEditor
React component.
When both CKEditor instances are loaded, the standalone CKEditor fails to render correctly, and the console displays the following error:

CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
This error suggests that multiple instances of CKEditor libraries are being loaded, causing conflicts.
Steps to Reproduce:

Setup:

Install CKEditor 5 and Formio dependencies in your project.
Configure and use both CKEditor instances in your application.


Error Occurrence:

Load the page containing both CKEditor instances.
Open or interact with the Formio CKEditor instance.
The standalone CKEditor instance breaks, and the ckeditor-duplicated-modules error
appears in the console.




ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/dist/index.js:1183:12)


Questions:

How can I avoid loading multiple instances of CKEditor libraries?
What are the best practices for using multiple CKEditor instances in a single project?
Is there a recommended approach to integrate CKEditor from Formio alongside a standalone CKEditor instance without causing conflicts?

Additional Information:
Versions Used:

"formiojs": "^4.20.0",
"ckeditor5": "^43.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^9.0.0",

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
